# Nativescript: How to create a JS File object from file path?

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm using nativescript-imagepicker plugin to select images from phone gallery. One of the things this plugin allows me to get, is the path to the file.

I need to be able to upload this selected file to a server, using form data. For that i need to create a file object first.

How can i use a file path, to create a file object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploading images from the photo gallery I would highly suggest using [Nativescsript background http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http). To upload the images to the server you will have to save them within the app so that they can be uploaded. I followed the example shown here [Upload example](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/app/ns-framework-modules-category/image-source/save-image/save-image-page.js#L49-L67).

Once you have saved the images locally if you want additional data you will need to use `multipartUpload` and construct a request that would look something like this.

```
let BackgroundHTTP = require('nativescript-background-http')
let session = BackgroundHTTP.session('some unique session id')
let request: {
    url: 'your.url.to/upload/images',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
    description: 'Uploading local images to the server'
}

//photos should have at least the filename from when you saved it locally.
let params = []
photos.forEach(photo => {
    params.push({name: photo.name, filename: photo.filename, value: 'ANY STRING DATA YOU NEED'})
}

let task = session.multipartUpload(params, request)

task.on('progress', evt => {
    console.log('upload progress: ' + ((evt.currentBytes / evt.totalBytes) * 100).toFixed(1) + '%')
}

task.on('error', evt => {
    console.log('upload error')
    console.log(evt)
}

task.on('complete', evt => {
    //this does not mean the server had a positive response
    //but the images hit the server.
    // use evt.responseCode to determine the status of request
    console.log('upload complete, status: ' + evt.responseCode)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to say i don't understand why i need to "save the image within the app". Can't i just create a File object from the existing file in the gallery, just like it would be done using a normal HTML form?

Comment: @sheff2k1 I'm not sure the reasoning behind needing a local copy. I had gotten the filepath same as you and was struggling to get anything to upload. After a few days of struggle and reading similar issues to this https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/221 I ended up following the way everyone else seems to do it. Creating a local copy seems to be the best solution. On upload complete I remove the local photo to save space.

Comment: You might not always have access to the original file while picking form gallery, so it's recommend you write it to a file if you like to access it often within your app. Also you should use background http plugin as the default http client do not support multipart upload. Another alternative is to upload the image as base64 string if you wish to not use background http plugin for upload.

Comment: So i managed(more or less) to use the session.uploadFile method, like it's shown in the standard example(using a file existing in my gallery, didn't go through any special file copying procedure.). But, the multipartUpload just doesn't work for me. let task = session.multipartUpload(params, request) doesn't return anything, and nothing happens. I tried deep diving into the code and it seems that it just "breaks" in some inner function call of the library, without any error whatsoever. Did you actually try running the multipartUpload? doubt the permissions are an issue,cause a single file works

Comment: I will also add that this weird thing happens even if i do not use any file in the "params" array, but only some standard fields .

Comment: LOL ok so i got the problem: I was using a number instead of a string, in my additional param. Pity the plugin doesn't throw any error, would've saved a lot of lost time :D . Sorry for bombing you with this :D